# Entity framework: Generic get with Icollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using a generic method that can return a specific set of entities.

```
public virtual IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where,
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    List<T> list;
    using (var context = new eTRdataEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

        //Apply eager loading
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

        list = dbQuery
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(where)
            .ToList<T>();
    }
    return list;
}
```

I have three classes called Domain, Term and Word. The domain contains multiple Terms and a term can have many instances of Word. Hence they are defined as Icollections

e.g.

```
public virtual ICollection<Terms> Terms{ get; set; }
```

I have already used the following command:

```
IGenericDataService<Domain> domain_= new DataManagementService<Domain>();
IList<Domain> tempDom = domain_.GetList(o => o.OID.Equals("ABC"), d => d.Term);
```

This returns the domain and all its terms, however does not return the word.

What I need to know is to how to call this method and direct it to get the Term as well as the Word (eager loading). The problem arises as the Domain has a collection of Terms and I cannot call it like,

```
IList<Domain> tempDom = domain_.GetList(o => o.OID.Equals("ABC"), d => d.Term.Word);
```

Please advice,

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` with nested collections:

```
IList<Domain> tempDom = domain_.GetList(o => o.OID.Equals("ABC"), 
                                        d => d.Term.Select(t => Words));
```

See also: [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

By the way, I would change the `Func where` parameter into an `Expression<Func>>`.

Comment: Do you mean public virtual IList<T> GetList(Expression<Func> where,
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.